# SQL how to create a aggregation for this problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have this table with cod, date of insertion (dat_valid_ini) and flag.
I need to aggregate only when the flag has changed and when aggregate show only the lowest dat_valid_ini.

The table I have:

| COD | DAT_VALID_INI | FLG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1088184 | 1900/01/01 | O |
| 1088184 | 2019/11/03 | B |
| 1088184 | 2020/02/12 | B |
| 1088184 | 2020/03/29 | B |
| 1088184 | 2020/03/31 | B |
| 1088184 | 2020/06/21 | O |

The table I need as result:

| COD | DAT_VALID_INI | FLG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1088184 | 1900/01/01 | O |
| 1088184 | 2019/11/03 | B |
| 1088184 | 2020/06/21 | O |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the first time a flag appears after a change.
Just use `lag()` and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(flg) over (partition by cod order by dat_valid_ini) as prev_flg
      from t
     ) t
where prev_flg is null or prev_flg <> flg;
```

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved my problem. I was using lead that is why wasn't working.